# ¿Cómo actualizar el Meta_Value de todos los post que se relacionen con un term?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un problema que limita el avance de mi proyecto y es el siguiente:

Actualmente tengo un query que me permite actualizar el `meta_key` `post_view_count` de todos mis post.

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET meta_value = %d WHERE meta_key = %s", 0, 'post_views_count' ) );
```

El problema es que esa query me actualiza todos los `meta_value`. Lo que he estado buscando es poder actualizar el `meta_value` de la `Meta_key` `post_view_count` de los posts presentes en la taxonomía "Autos", y cuyo term de dicha taxonomía sea "Azules". De esta manera evitaría actualizar el `post_view_count` de autos Rojos, por ejemplo.

¿Es posible?

Comment: Seguramente sea posible y algún experto en wordpress quizás pueda contestarte. No obstante, si mostraras la estructura de la base de datos (dónde están esos campos que te interesan), probablemente haya más personas que puedan contestarte, por más que no usen wordpress.